# build is not working when building the project

Tags: liferay-7

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Settings file '/Users/x032206/Workspace/emph-liferay/liferay/settings.gradle' line: 23
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'liferay'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.liferay.workspace'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.liferay.gradle.plugins.workspace.WorkspaceExtension.
> > com/liferay/portal/tools/bundle/support/commands/DownloadCommand

I am using java 17 and java 11
not working with both of them .